# Breakdown of signature verification in CertificateVerify (TLS 1.3) with RSA-PSS

Tags: tls, certificates, digital-signature

I'm debugging a TLS v1.3 client program, which failed to verify the signature in server's `CertificateVerify`, so I'm  learning the procedures for verifying the signature from server's `CertificateVerify` handshake message.

Here's my understanding after reading RFC8446 and related articles, is there anything wrong or I'm misunderstanding ?

- It is mandatory to support signature scheme `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256`, RSASSA-PSS algorithm must be used in `CertificateVerify`
- To generate RSA signature in `CertificateVerify` on server side,  one must generate "digital signature", that is a concatenation of **(1)** octet `0x20` consecutively repeated 64 times, **(2)** the context string `TLS 1.3, server CertificateVerify`, **(3)** A single byte `0x00` as the separator **(4)** the hash output of hankshake messages until server's `Certificate`, in other words :

```
Transcript-Hash(ClientHello || ServerHello || EncryptedExtension || server Certificate)
```

(assume the server doesn't send `CertificateRequest`)

- Assume `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256` is used, then hash the "digital signature" described above with SHA-256.
- Encode the hash output of "digital signature" using **(1)** an  PKCS#1 PSS algorithm, **(2)** salt length (equal to hash output size of `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256` , based on assumption above)
- Sign the PSS-encoded value above using **(1)** RSA encryption algorithm **(2)** RSA private key corresponding to the certificate sent in previous `Certificate` handshake message.
- The signed (encrypted) value above is the signature of the server's handshake message `CertificateVerify`.

Here's how the client verifies signature from server's `CertificateVerify`. Is there anything wrong or I'm misunderstanding ?

1. Generate "digital signature" as described above, the hash output of handshake messages `Transcript-Hash(ClientHello .... server Certificate)` is also the same as described above, then hash the "digital signature" according to the chosen signature scheme (assume it's `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256`).
2. Decrypt the signature in the `CertificateVerify` using (1) RSA public key extracted from server's certificate in the previous handshake message `Certificate`, (2) RSA encryption algorithm, then it produces PSS-encoded value.
3. Verify the PSS-encoded value in the step above, with the hash output of "digital signature" in the first step, using  **(1)** PKCS#1 PSS decode function, and **(2)** appropriate salt length (e.g. output size of SHA-256)

Thanks for reading, any suggestion / tip is appreciated.

**[EDIT, 2019.12.25]**

The verification procedure in the post above should be correct after I solve few implementation errors on the TLS 1.3 client program and I manage to verify the signature with `CertificateVerify` sent by server.

I also found [this website](https://tls13.ulfheim.net/), which provides good example of TLS v1.3 handshake process , for those who need to learn the detail.